# Is there any way to take action against peer review?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently [proposed an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15832800) for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650497/4816207). Actually, the developer who has given the answer has added HTML code as an external link (jsfiddle). So I copied the content of jsfiddle link and pasted in the default Stack Overflow snippet. But the author of the answer has rejected my suggestion by giving the following explanation:

> **zsong reviewed this 17 hours ago:**
>
> Reject This edit does not make the
> post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate
> or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or
> actively harm readability.

I believe, the reason given by him did not make any sense in this case. So is there any way to take action against such reviews?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this isn't a review audit, so that tag is inappropriate for this question.  Not entirely sure what the correct tag is, but that isn't it.  That aside, since you are discussing a specific user's actions, have you taken the time to notify them of this discussion?

Comment: No, there is no way to take legal action against such reviews. The idea that there would be is nonsensical.

Comment: So then this peer review process is a major fallback.

Comment: @Daedalus I removed that tag.

Comment: Am I right in presuming that you don't mean "legal action" as in "a process to have a court of law settle an argument", and that you are just asking about things that might be done according to the site rules?

Comment: hahaha. No way sir!

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal: Please be aware that the OP of the answer themselves rejected your suggested edit. I don't know JavaScript, but the most relevant code seems to be already in the answer. Maybe the OP doesn't see the need to put a full-blown example into the answer for reasons of clarity.

Comment: @honk what if in future that external link is no more or broken. That is why stackoverflow introduced html, js, css code snippet . https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal: Then the answer will still work, because the relevant code is in the answer. The linked full-blown example seems to add some easy code in order to quickly test the relevant code. This might be convenient, but I guess that any user who knows a little JavaScript can quickly code that by themselves.

Comment: You are aware that the reject reason is just a standard text? People [have asked for a friendlier wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270583/168333).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> legal action

Reviewers aren't breaking any laws regardless of the decision they make on a suggested edit. So no, you can't take legal action against them. Threatening to sue just because you disagree with someone's harmless opinion is simply not going to fly anyway, and all it does is make *you* look bad.

> If this is the reason, then stackoverflow should not give that feature.

Just because they gave you Stack Snippets doesn't mean you have to use it all the time.

It's nice that you are converting an external fiddle to a Stack Snippet, and in an ideal world most code snippets would be presented as Stack Snippets subject to their limitations, but there are no rules requiring external fiddles to be converted for every post. An exception of course is when the code that's in the post fails to do what it's supposed to do: illustrate the point given by the answer, and it's actually the code in the fiddle that does that correctly.

Even so, a post author is always given the binding vote over suggested edits to their own post.

Comment: from legal action I didn't mean court related thing. It more related to the SO community standard.

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal _In this particular case_, it is an arbitrary decision. All the required information is already in the answer. So there's no harm if the link dies. The OP decided against inlining the demo in the answer. An arbitrary decision, but the OP has final word in these things.